# Dimensionality in Projections

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm new to linear algebra and I'm somewhat confused about dimensionality in projections. Having said that, this confusion is probably owing to an incomplete understanding of multi-dimensional space.

To illustrate this confusion, let's assume an orthogonal projection of a vector $\vec{v} = (v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ onto a plane, $P$.

Given that $\vec{v}$ is three-dimensional and a plane, by definition, is two-dimensional, is the above instance projecting from three-dimensions to two-dimensions?

I was hoping somebody could explain what is happening in the above instance from a standpoint of dimensionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the orthogonal projection to plane $P$ is defined for *all* vectors $v\in\Bbb R^3$, and therefore is basically a $\Bbb R^3\to P$ function, call it $\phi$, which happens to be linear (preserving $\lambda\cdot$ and $+$ operations, for $\lambda$ ranging all reals), provided the origin is in $P$.

However, it is very natural to follow this projection by the *inclusion* (embedding) $\iota:P\to \Bbb R^3$ which maps any vector $p\in P$ to $p$ itself (can be done, as $P\subseteq\Bbb R^3$). This way, the composite function $\iota\circ\phi:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ is also regarded as the orthogonal projection to $P$, and we get that the *image* of $\iota\circ\phi$ is exactly the 'subspace' $P$, and that the *rank* of $\iota\circ\phi$ is its dimension, $2$.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response.


Extrapolating from your answer, is it correct to say,


given that $P \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, we can establish the following equivalence relation:


$$\phi : \mathbb{R}^{3} \mapsto P \equiv \phi : \mathbb{R}^{3} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{2} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{3}$$


This would also correspond with the property that the restricted codomain (image) of $\iota \circ \phi$ is of dimension 2.

Comment: Well, the notation '$P\in\Bbb R^2$' means something else, you want to say that $P$ is a subplane (subspace) of $\Bbb R^3$ (in notation usually $P\le\Bbb R^3$)with $\dim P=2$. Also, at least as I studied, $x\mapsto y$ is the correspondence itself: the element $x$ is mapped to $y$ and $\Bbb R^3\to P$ denotes the whole function (which asserts these correspondence). About the equivalence relation between orthogonal projections and the projected subspaces, it indeed exists (though not necessarily restricted to subplanes).